# Symfony FosUserBundle show only user with role == ROLE_USER

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I am trying to get only user with `ROLE_USER`.

I have this in my controller:

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
->createQuery(
        'SELECT u FROM StageUserBundle:User u WHERE u.roles LIKE :role'
)->setParameter('role', '%"ROLE_USER"%' 
);
$users = $query->getResult();
```

It worked with `ROLE_ADMIN` instead of `ROLE_USER` but I need to show only `User.getRoles()== "ROLE_USER"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Found the solution to my problem .
i changed this in my controller :

```
$query = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM StageUserBundle:User u WHERE NOT u.roles LIKE :role'
    )->setParameter('role', '%"ROLE_ADMIN"%' );

    $users = $query->getResult();
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that the User model in FOSUserBundle never actually has the `ROLE_USER`.

<kbd>FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface</kbd>

```
const ROLE_DEFAULT = 'ROLE_USER';
```

<kbd>FOS\UserBundle\Model\User</kbd>

```
public function addRole($role)
{
    $role = strtoupper($role);
    if ($role === static::ROLE_DEFAULT) {
        return $this;
    }

    if (!in_array($role, $this->roles, true)) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
    }

    return $this;
}

....

public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = $this->roles;

    foreach ($this->getGroups() as $group) {
        $roles = array_merge($roles, $group->getRoles());
    }

    // we need to make sure to have at least one role
    $roles[] = static::ROLE_DEFAULT;

    return array_unique($roles);
}
```

When you `getRoles` it add the `ROLE_USER` as a default and when you `addRole` it check to see if the role is `ROLE_USER` and then skips if it does.

In reality every user on your system will have the `ROLE_USER` so to find all users with the role you can just do a `SELECT u FROM StageUserBundle:User u`.